# ASP.NET Dirty in the context of ViewState

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

What does "dirty" mean in the context of ViewState?

How does ViewState benefit from marking something as "dirty"?

Comment: ey Babu,
I can't understand what you mean with "dirty".

Comment: It is rude to ask for advice and tell people how not to give it.

Comment: @Oded  :Sorry,Just I was interested in   knowing  answers rather  to  read other   blogs.If it  hurt  other,i am very  sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about the [IsItemDirty-property of the StateBag class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.statebag.isitemdirty.aspx)? This property is used to mark whether or not a particular item has been changed during the current request.

Here's a rather old article that explains some of it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188774.aspx

Comment: Yes I am  talking about IsItemDirty.Thank  you